# Flask app not connecting to the port

Tags: python, flask, localhost

I'm following the Flask Web Development Tutorial by Miguel Grinberg, and I've copied this code

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And on Jupyter I get this result: 
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit: 1

If I open http://127.0.0.1:5000/ the page is just loading forever, same thing if I run the code on the Powershell (but without giving the error).
I've tried to look for similar questions but I wasn't able to find something, can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong and what I can do to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
As Mariusz asks, here there is the error I get by add %tb at the beginning of the cell:

```
SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-5757c6364c65> in <module>()
      8     return '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'
      9 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 10     app.run(debug=True)

C:\Users\Antonio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py in run(self, host, port, debug, **options)
    841         options.setdefault('passthrough_errors', True)
    842         try:
--> 843             run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
    844         finally:
    845             # reset the first request information if the development server

C:\Users\Antonio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py in run_simple(hostname, port, application, use_reloader, use_debugger, use_evalex, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type, threaded, processes,     request_handler, static_files, passthrough_errors, ssl_context)
    690         from ._reloader import run_with_reloader
    691         run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval,
--> 692                           reloader_type)
    693     else:
    694         inner()

C:\Users\Antonio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\_reloader.py in run_with_reloader(main_func, extra_files, interval, reloader_type)
    248             reloader.run()
    249         else:
--> 250             sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
    251     except KeyboardInterrupt:
    252         pass

SystemExit: 1
```

Comment: Can you add `%tb` at the top of the cell (as message says) and update question with traceback?

Comment: why do you need Jupyter here? You example works fine just by running python yourfile.py

Comment: ffeast, it's not just a problem with Jupyter, with Jupyter I have an error while on Powershell not, but I'm unable to see the page at http://127.0.0.1:5000/ with the Powershell too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you pls try this code and see if it works

```
app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```